# React-Redux componentWillReceiveProps not triggered using api data

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, json-server

I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do things, or if it's even possible, therefore my question here.

I'm using react-redux, redux-thunk, json-server (for dummy data) and typescript in my project. With 1 api call I update the 'data' reducer with all the data for my application. This data is used together with other reducers through combineReducers:
[Redux tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcHAc.png)

What I'd like to do is map data.labels as prop into my component. Once the whole api call finishes, and data.labels is therefore filled, I would like to show this data to my front-end. I have however noticed that the componentWillReceiveProps is not triggered at all when my data api call is finished. It does update if I attach the whole 'data' prop to my component, instead of 'data.labels'.

Reducer:

```
    case Actions.RECEIVE:
        return {
            ...state,
            labels: action.payload.labels,
            defaultLinks: action.payload.defaultLinks,
            customLinks: action.payload.customLinks
        };
```

Component:

```
function mapStateToProps(state: any) {
return {
    labels: state.data.labels, // This will not trigger componentWillReceiveProps

function mapStateToProps(state: any) {
return {
    data: state.data, // This will trigger componentWillReceiveProps
```

Any tips on how to get this to work without injecting the whole data object as prop?

**Edit**

In the case of using te full 'data', I get an empty array of labels when logging data.labels in componentWillReceiveProps before the data has been fetched. After the data has been successfully fetched, my log shows an array of x amount of labels.

Below are the interfaces I use:
Data interface (structure inside redux store, with 'data' as parent):

```
interface Data {
  labels: Label[];
  defaultLinks: DefaultLink[];
  customLinks: CustomLink[];
  request: boolean;
  failure: boolean;
}
```

Props interface used in my component:

```
interface Props {
  labels: Label[];
  ...; // Other stuff
}
```

Comment: You may be looking for the selector pattern: https://gist.github.com/abhiaiyer91/aaf6e325cf7fc5fd5ebc70192a1fa170

often used in combination with reselect: https://github.com/reactjs/reselect#reselect

Comment: I think your dispatched label data is same with previous data. Therefore, componentWillReceiveProps doesn't trigger.

Comment: Can you share the props interface you are using?

Comment: @brub thanks for that! Seems like an interesting idea so I'll give it a shot!

Comment: @metinata Updated my post, a log shows that there is a difference in data in the before and after, so the method should be triggered I think?

Comment: @Alejandro, Updated my post with my interfaces :)

Comment: @brub Thanks that was the answer! Could you post it as answer so I can give you some credit? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be looking for the selector pattern: [gist.github.com/abhiaiyer91/aaf6e325cf7fc5fd5ebc70192a1fa170](https://gist.github.com/abhiaiyer91/aaf6e325cf7fc5fd5ebc70192a1fa170) often used in combination with reselect: [github.com/reactjs/reselect#reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect#reselect)

The primary advantage is you decouple the shape of your state from the shape of your props.